# How can I use foreach loop on named range in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I've been going through the documentation and SO for about an hour without a simple answer to this.

I'm retrieving my named range like this...

```
$properties_table = $objPHPExcel->getNamedRanges("lookuptableproperties");
foreach( $properties_table as $name => $range ):
    echo "<pre>";
    var_dump( $range );
    echo "</pre>";
    break;
endforeach;
```

I want to do something like this...

```
foreach( $range as $row ):
    //then loop through all the cells in this row
    $row->cells(1,1) //similar to VBA
endforeach;
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try foreach($row->cells as $cell) ? Just throwing a guess :)

Comment: no such luck. You would think it would be that easy

Comment: hehe sorry about that. That was a blind guess :) Anyway can you do var_dump($range) and var_dump($row) and show us a single row output? we may get a clue there.

Comment: I can't do a single row, only the entire range, but every variable is private, so I need an accessor

Answer (score 0):

```
$line=1; 
while ($line<$range){
    $lineString = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($line=1);
    $row->cells($coluna.'1');
    $line++;
}
```

Use this to go by each line. A1->B1->C1...

Its no a foreach but in the worst case you should be able to adpt.